# как умножить данные из radio и из select

Tags: javascript, html

При выборе radio выводит данные на экран, не обходимо чтоб еще выводило произведение select и radio так  же на экран, не могу разобраться как сделать PS. результат должен быть в

Total:

в лейбл

```js
    function radioget(getValue) {
            document.getElementById('lblmess') .innerHTML= getValue; 
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <title>test</title>
</head>
<body> 
<input type="radio" name="radioName" value="13" onchange="radioget($ (this).val())"><label>Car</label>
<hr/>
<input type="radio" name="radioName" value="22" onchange="radioget($ (this).val())"><label>Bike</label>
<hr/>
<input type="radio" name="radioName" value="34" onchange="radioget($ (this).val())"><label>Train</label>
<br>
<br>
<label id="lblmess"></label>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<select id="list">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<div class="total">
<p>Total: </p><label id=" price"></label>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function radioget(getValue) {
  document.getElementById('lblmess').innerText = getValue;
  // выбираем select с кол-вом товара
  let list = document.getElementById('list');
  // вызываем функцию которая отображает total
  // используя value выше выбранного select'a
  showTotal(list.value);  
}

function showTotal(amount) {
  // product - выбранный radio input
  let product = document.querySelector('input[name="radioName"]:checked');
  // если product выбран (есть input checked)
  // тотал = кол-во умножаем на цену
  // если product не выбран total = 0
  let total = product ? (amount * product.value) : 0;
  document.getElementById('price').innerText = total;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radioName" value="13" onchange="radioget(this.value)"><label>Car</label>
<hr/>
<input type="radio" name="radioName" value="22" onchange="radioget(this.value)"><label>Bike</label>
<hr/>
<input type="radio" name="radioName" value="34" onchange="radioget(this.value)"><label>Train</label>
<br>
<br>
<label id="lblmess"></label>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<select id="list" onchange="showTotal(this.value)">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<div class="total">
<p>Total: </p><label id="price"></label>
</div>
```